# Getting byte[] from database is time consuming

Tags: java, database, jpa, binary, pdfbox

I am saving the font in the database as binary, each time I take out the font it takes 1-2 minutes with a font size of 3 mb. Is there any way to fix this. Thank you.

```
    private PDFont getFont(PDDocument doc, DesignElement designElement)
        throws IOException {
    OTFParser otfParser = new OTFParser();
    TTFParser ttfParser = new TTFParser();
    byte[] bytes = designElement.getFontMaster().getFontFile();
    InputStream inputStream = ByteSource.wrap(bytes).openStream();
    if (designElement.getFontMaster().getExt().equals("otf")) {
        OpenTypeFont otf = otfParser.parse(inputStream);
        return PDType0Font.load(doc, otf, false);
    } else {
        TrueTypeFont ttf = ttfParser.parse(inputStream);
        return PDType0Font.load(doc, ttf, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the database have to do with this?  I don't see any database code.  My guess is that the parsing of the binary into the font object is what is taking the lion's share of the time here.

Comment: Can you share the code when you are retrieving the data from the DB?

Comment: I use Spring Data JPA, I simply call it with findbyid() method.

Comment: designElement.getFont Master(). getFontFile(). The Font Master is associated with the Design Element. I get designElement with findbyId(). 
Later getFontFile() is a method to get binary.

Comment: I have posted the table structure below

Comment: Why not use a `ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: Have you run a profiler to determine where excactly the time is spent?

Comment: I ran and recorded the time for getFont(), about 2 minutes with a 3 mb font. I would try using a ByteArrayInputStream to see if it improves the time. I will report back in this post.

Comment: Does `designElement.getFontMaster()` itself cost time? You're calling it twice. You're also generating a parser object that you don't use (but this isn't really relevant re: time).